# virt-sysprep doesn't change hostname

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I use KVM-based virtualization on my fedora 30 OS to run 3 virtual machines, runnung `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with a mini Hadoop cluster for test purposes.

The storage for virtual machines in configured to use file, mapped to LVM logical volumes.

First I created one machine `master` and then, after creating new logical volume for next machine, used `virt-clone` to create another one, `slave1`. Then I ran `virt-sysprep --hostname slave1 -d slave1` and green-colored output contained line like `changing hostname`, but after I logged in to `slave1` I found that hostname doesn't actually change and is the same as source VM has - `master` which is not what I expected.

All examples I've found used `qcow` image for VM storage, maybe it is related to my issue somehow, but I don't have enough expertise to find it out.  Please note that I didn't use storage pool to create VM's storage.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late on an answer but I had to add `--enable customize` to the command to get it to set the hostname.